# Invalid Syntax, when running for loop

Tags: python

I was practising some exercises in Python. And Python interpreter has generated error saying: `Invalid Syntax` when I tried to run the below posted code:

**Python code**:

```
#Use of Enumerate:
for i,v in enumerate (['item0', 'item01', 'item02']) :
    print (i, ":", v)
```

Comment: please fix the indentation. Also, the code, properly indented, does work, please post the stacktrace and more code

Comment: Is this python 2.7 or python 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given space for print statement you can check [Python: Myths about Indentation](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk)

```
for i,v in enumerate (['item0', 'item01', 'item02']):
    print (i, ":", v)
```

Answer (score 2):

Indent is important:

```
for i,v in enumerate (['item0', 'item01', 'item02']):
    print (i, ":", v)
```

---

```
0 : item0
1 : item01
2 : item02
```

Comment: but the interpreter highlights the the ":" after the if-statement and generate the error message i posted

Comment: sorry I meant the for loop statement

Answer (score 0):

In Python indentation is everything.

```
for i,v in enumerate (['item0', 'item01', 'item02']):
    print (i, ":", v)
```